# android dexclassloader get list of all classes

Tags: android, classloader

I am using external jar from assets or sdcard in my android application. To do that I am using DexClassLoader.

```
DexClassLoader cl = new DexClassLoader(dexInternalStoragePath.getAbsolutePath(),
                        optimizedDexOutputPath.getAbsolutePath(),
                        null,
                        getClassLoader());
```

to load a  class :

```
Class myNewClass = cl.loadClass("com.example.dex.lib.LibraryProvider");
```

it works really nice but now I want to get list of all classes names in my DexClassLoader 
I found [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html#getInitiatedClasses%28java.lang.ClassLoader%29) to work in java but there is no such thing in android.

Question is how i can get list of all classes names from DexClassLoader

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To list all classes in a .jar file containing a `classes.dex` file you use `DexFile`, not `DexClassLoader`, e.g. like this:

```
String path = "/path/to/your/library.jar"
try {
    DexFile dx = DexFile.loadDex(path, File.createTempFile("opt", "dex",
            getCacheDir()).getPath(), 0);
    // Print all classes in the DexFile
    for(Enumeration<String> classNames = dx.entries(); classNames.hasMoreElements();) {
        String className = classNames.nextElement();
        System.out.println("class: " + className);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.w(TAG, "Error opening " + path, e);
}
```

Comment: Despite the comment in http://developer.android.com/reference/dalvik/system/DexFile.html#loadDex(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, int) that "This function should not be called directly by an application" `DexFile.loadDex()` does appear to be the only way to examine a dex file - a simple `new DexFile(File)` throws an `IoException`.

Comment: When I´m trying to read all classes from the jar, I´m only getting all classes from the current running application, but not the classes from the jar file. I don´t understand whats going on

Comment: Can you get the actual classes?

Comment: Despite entries clearly including my classpath, loadClass() with my classpath and ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader() returns null, what can I do to fix it, aka load the class I'm after?

Comment: DexFile is deprecated as of API26 and is slated for actual removal