# loadClass() method giving ClassNotFoundException if JAR is not included in libs folder

Tags: android

I am trying to load classes from JAR file at runtime in my android application. I am using DexClassLoader for it.

I am doing it like below steps:-
  Some JAR file is present in some memory location on harddisk. I am preparing dex file from that JAR and storing it in application's appdex folder.
Then I am using DexClassLoader to load class and then creating instance of class and calling its methods using Interface.

Problem - It is working only if I am including JAR file in libs folder of android project (on eclipse).
If I am removing JAR file from libs folder, then while calling loadClass() method, it is throwing ClassNotFoundException.
Ideally it should have worked without including JAR in libs folder. I want to remove that dependency (from libs folder).

Am I missing something ?

P.S. - I have created separate android project from which I am creating JAR and using it as plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that this error is due to the path you specify for the `dex` file being incorrect.

See the answer to [this question: android dexclassloader get list of all classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12195642/android-dexclassloader-get-list-of-all-classes). If you path is incorrect then the approach suggested will give you an exception.